# Readonly local variable cannot be used as an assignment target

Tags: c#

If I have:

```
var myObjects = new ConcurrentBag<object>();
```

And try to remove objects via:

```
foreach (var myObject in myObjects.ToArray())
{
    myObjects.TryTake(out myObject);
}
```

The compiler complains with: "Readonly local variable cannot be used as an assignment target"

Yet, if I add a local reference within the foreach it compiles:

```
foreach (var myObject in myObjects.ToArray())
{
    var localReference = myObject;
    myObjects.TryTake(out localReference);
}
```

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: In the second loop, just declare `object localReference;` without assignement, since the `out` parameter is ALWAYS assigned a value. A method does not compile, if its `out` parameter is not assigned a value before returning.

Comment: By the way, `foreach` would work directly on `myObjects`. The conversion with `ToArray()` makes no sense in your example and can simply be dropped.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The iteration variable in a `foreach` (i.e. `myObject`) **cannot** be assigned a new value inside the `foreach`. It is not allowed.

In the first scenario, the `out` tries to do this. In the second scenario, you *never try to reassign to `myObject`, so it is fine.

To quote from the ECMA specification, 15.8.4, emphasis mine:

> 1. The type and identifier of a foreach statement declare the
>      iteration variable of the statement.
> 2. The iteration variable corresponds to a **read-only local
>      variable** with a scope that extends over the embedded statement.
> 3. During execution of a foreach statement, the iteration variable
>      represents the collection element for which an iteration is
>      currently being performed.
> 4. A **compile-time error occurs** if the embedded statement attempts
>      to modify the iteration variable (via assignment or the ++ and
>      --operators) or pass the iteration variable **as a ref or out parameter**.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to assign the retrieved object to the array, use a for-statement instead, since you cannot assign a value to the loop variable

```
object[] arr = myObjects.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    myObjects.TryTake(out arr[i]); 
}
```

Now the array contains the retrieved objects or null where no object could be taken.

---

#### UPDATE

After having read about `ConcurrentBag<T>`, I think I am beginning to understand what you have in mind. My first solution above runs into race conditions in multithreaded scenarios (the very and only reson for using a `ConcurrentBag<T>`). Try this instead

```
var removedObjects = new List<object>();
object obj;
while (myObjects.TryTake(out obj)) {
    removedObjects.Add(obj);
}
```

Note: Assigning the objects of the bag to an array and then looping through it is not a good idea, since other threads could have added or removed objects meanwhile. Therefore you must use this direct approach.

---

If you only want to remove the objects without retrieving them at the same time:

```
object obj;
while (myObjects.TryTake(out obj)) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is a much better way to remove the objects.  I will be changing my code to work this way.  (However, I think Marc's answer is a more clear explanation of what is going on.)